# How to do texture modification

Tags: iphone, opengl-es

I am working on iphone opengl es. I am a newbie to this. Can any one guide me how to proceed..

Answer (score 1):

First, start with: [Apple - Drawing with OpenGL ES](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/3DDrawing/Conceptual/OpenGLES_ProgrammingGuide/WorkingwithEAGLContexts/WorkingwithEAGLContexts.html). Then [GLSprite](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/samplecode/GLSprite/index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40007325) and [The Red Book](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/).

After that, these are very handy: [Lessens from Molecules](http://www.sunsetlakesoftware.com/2008/08/05/lessons-molecules-opengl-es), [Apple Technical notes](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/technotes/tn2008/tn2230.html) and [Khronos - OpenGL ES Reference](http://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/1.1/docs/man/).

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you start with Apple's example code.  The GLSprite example might be a good place to start.

For general Open GL programming, [the red book](http://www.glprogramming.com/red/) is a great learning guide as well.